# Azure Active Directory B2C User Management

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I was following [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet/) article and created a sample which works perfectly well. I can sign up, sign out and edit my profile with it but can't find out how to add a user in AAD B2C and assign it some role, so that I can differentiate them on the basis of roles, i.e. when I get to the Claims Page and get a user object, I can check the user by writing something like this:

```
User.IsInRole("client")
```

I added a custom attribute in "User Attributes" with the name of "Role" but that didn't solve my problem. I can only see that when I write:

```
foreach (Claim claim in ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims)
...claim.Type .... claim.Value
```

But I want it as I explained above

Thanks in advance.

**Ok by now,** I have found out the roles by clicking on the directory name -- users, but the available roles are User, Global Admin, Billing Admin, Service Admin, User Admin and Password Admin, but User.IsInRole("User") didn't work for me. So,
 1. can I add any customized roles
 2. how can I check if my user belongs to a particular role programmatically?
Thanks.

Comment: There is at least a feature request for *group* claims: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/10123836-get-user-membership-groups-in-the-claims-with-ad-b

Answer (score 2):

You can add custom roles by modifying application manifest file (application configured in Azure Active Directory). You just have to download manifest json file, add your custom roles and upload file again. You can do it here:
[image]

Then open the file and add custom role like that:

```
  "appRoles": [
{
  "allowedMemberTypes": [
    "User"
  ],
  "description": "some text",
  "displayName": "Super role",
  "id": "c530a40b-a47c-42b7-ba9a-f34d8ca7e443",
  "isEnabled": true,
  "origin": "Application",
  "value": "Super role"
}
```

],

Comment: This is for Azure AD, are you sure this works for Azure B2C?

Comment: Should work too in mu opinion. You also have to define application inside of your Azure AD. Works fine with B2B:)

Comment: @dawdir
I couldn't see any option to download the manifest file, probably it's not available in AAD B2C, I can only see 3 column headings (Display Name, User Name, Sourced From) when I select my directory configured as B2C and 3 options at the bottom panel (Add User, Reset Password, Delete).
Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Sam, you need to select an application in the old portal in B2C to see this, not sure if these applications are the same as the ones in the new portal

Comment: Yes, you have to do it in Azure Management Portal: https://manage.windowsazure.com/

Comment: I couldn't find any option to download the manifest in AAD B2C, would appreciate if you provide some screenshot.

Comment: @sam is right, there is no such option in the management portal for a B2C instance...

Comment: if you upload back the manifest file with the changes, it says **ParameterValidationException=Invalid parameters provided; BadRequestException=Updates to converged applications are not allowed in this version.; ** for a b2c application

Answer (score 0):

User attributes in Azure B2C are prefixed with "Extension_", so a user attribute "Role" will be called "extension_role" in your claims.
This is the reason the UserIsInRole doesn't work

Something that works for Azure AD, maybe for B2C also(not tried by me):
Try to use Groups (create a new group), add the user to the group.
Group membership isn't added to your claims by default:
http://justazure.com/azure-active-directory-part-4-group-claims/